# Why Event.fireAsync() requires an @ObservesAsync annotation?

Tags: java, events, jakarta-ee, cdi, cdi-2.0

In CDI 2.0 one [can fire an event asynchronously](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/news/2017/05/19/tour-around-weld-3/#_async_events_and_notification_options) by calling `Event.fireAsync()` and then listen to this event by with a `@ObservesAsync` annotated listener.

Why do we need both `Event.firesAsync()` and `@ObservesAsync`?

- Couldn't CDI 2.0 process asynchronously an event fired by `Event.fire()` and caught with `@ObservesAsync`?
- Or reversely, why couldn't CDI 2.0 asynchronously process an event fired by `Event.fireAsync()` and caught with `@Observes`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A very good question indeed, here is a bit of insight.

CDI EG (expert group) decided against mixing those two for several reasons:

- Backward compatibility

  - Existing applications use synchronous and it needs to behave equally
  - Keeping the same annotation would require you to add extra option to differentiate anyway
- Return type

  - Calling `Event.fireAsync()` gives you a `CompletionStage` to which you can chain next steps with `exceptionally()` or `thenApply()` etc. This naturally fits into asynchronous programming model.
  - Good old `Event.fire()` only gives you `void`, to which you cannot react at all - not good for async
  - Again, the return value of synchronous one cannot be changed due to backward compatibility
- Excepting handling differs **a lot**

  - Exception in synchronous notification == end of chain, you blow up
  - Exception in asynchronous notification == you keep going and gather all exceptions from observer methods (possibly from multiple threads!) and then present them back to invoking code. Since it's `CompletionStage`, you can easily react to that.
  - Mixing the two would lead to a very confusing result on user side - when would you blow up and when do you keep going? What is the true outcome of `Event.fire()` (if it were for async as well)
- Internal observer processing

  - It would be very complex (assuming it would even be possible) to mix sync and async
  - Bear in mind that you need to strictly draw a line between which is going to be sync and async as contexts do not propagate in other threads (for instance `RequestScoped` needs to be re-activated, by Weld, in the async observer thread)
  - Similar troubles come with security context propagation for integrators
  - There is often pre-processing of observers to make it work really fast, if you have one observer method for both, you cannot really pre-process it as you never know what it will be used for

Other advantages of the current model I can think of:

- Presence of `fireAsync()` allows you to fire event with additional options

  - There are so called [`NotificationOptions`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#event) which allow you to specify an executor for your notifications
  - This also gives more firepower to implementations - Weld already offers [parallel execution and timeouts](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html_single/#_asynchronous_event_producers) through these options
- Last but not least - user experience

  - This way it is clear, that what you had before works exactly the same
  - And that for `fireAsync()` you have matching `@ObservesAsync`